# gnome-contacts-search-provider using all resources

Tags: gnome

I noticed that when I use GNOME Shell Activities menu search, my CPU usage on first core jumps to 80 - 100 %. I checked the processes and found that gnome-contacts-search-provider is the cause.

What can I do about it?

Comment: I have the same problem! I solve it killing the process evry time I turn on the PC. But this is not a solution.

Answer (score 0):

This is expected, unless the high CPU usage remains for a long time

Answer (score 0):

Go to Settings | Search | Contacts | OFF